# Error handling with Javascript-enabled WCF?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wcf, microsoft-ajax, wcf-callbacks

Is there documentation on how to use the callback functions in a WCF Service that is exposed to Javascript?  I'm interested in getting information from the FailureCallback as to why my method isn't firing.

In other words I have the follwoing JavaScript code:

```
     function getWCF_RowNumber(parentID) {
              logEvent("<strong>Busy</strong>: Please wait while lower grid is refreshed...");                  
              var service = new ajaxTest();
              service.Vendor_GetParentRowNumber(parentID, moveBottomGridToRow, wcfFailCallback, null);
          }
```

How do I implement wcfFailCallback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using ASP.NET AJAX and not jQuery or some other 3rd party JavaScript library.

The ASP.NET AJAX failure callback takes a single parameter.  From MSDN, a sample failure callback would look like this:

```
function wcfFailCallback(error)
{
    var stackTrace = error.get_stackTrace();
    var message = error.get_message();
    var statusCode = error.get_statusCode();
    var exceptionType = error.get_exceptionType();
    var timedout = error.get_timedOut();

    // Display the error.    
    var RsltElem = 
        document.getElementById("Results");
    RsltElem.innerHTML = 
        "Stack Trace: " +  stackTrace + "<br/>" +
        "Service Error: " + message + "<br/>" +
        "Status Code: " + statusCode + "<br/>" +
        "Exception Type: " + exceptionType + "<br/>" +
        "Timedout: " + timedout;
}
```

So the `wcfFailCallback` function takes an `error` parameter, which has a number of properties that provide you information about what failed.

The full article on MSDN is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398995.aspx).  It goes into some decent amount of details about how to hook up WCF services to ASP.NET AJAX clients.

I hope this helps!!  If there are other questions or if I didn't fully understand your question, let me know and I'll update my answer accordingly.